# How to mark artifact build official to be used for deployments?

Tags: jenkins

My `Jenkins` has a `mvn install` jobs that builds artifacts (WAR files) that are later deployed to various server instances in various environments by separate jobs that do deployment. The policy in the deployment jobs is to take the artifacts from the latest successful build of the build job.

However, I would like to change to mark a specific build as official from which the deployment jobs should be taking artifacts in order to be able to get the latest from VC and do more builds but not to deploy them because they have not been marked. So the official build may be 5 builds down the list, which is what I consider stable/official because builds 1-4 are not yet stable. So I want to do more builds to make sure my stuff actually compiles and builds properly (some of my coworkers check in stuff that doesn't compile) but I am not yet ready to deploy them.

How can I do this in Jenkins? Does Jenkins come with functionality to do this or would it be yet another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it by using couple of Jenkins plugins. Install the plugin [Build Keeper](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Keeper+Plugin) and [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). So when you build stable WAR file mark that build to keep this build forever as shown in the image [Screenshot of build forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9h9Z.png)  and then in your deployment Job's use the copy artifacts plugin to copy the artifacts from the latest saved build [Screenshot showing the copy artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5C1N.png) so that it only gets the Stable WAR to deploy which you marked. Once you are ready to update it with the new build just unselect the old build which marked forever and select the new build so that the new artifact is used by the deployment Job's.